# Is testing relations in Rails considered to be a best practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, relationship

Wondering if testing of a relations in Rails widely considered to be a best practice or not.
We have disagreement on the team on testing relations.

IMO it's redundant, i.e. to have each `has_many :people` to be tested with `should have_many(:people)` as it looks repetitive, just copy-paste from model to a test - i.e. I cannot imagine it stop working or some other workflow break it, the only way to break it - is just remove or change the line (but if someone just changing code randomly that someone can also just remove the test as well). Moreover it doesn't actually test relation (like if Company returns people who have appropriate `company_id` and if company destroyed - people are actually destroyed - as it can actually fail in case of destroy validation or foreign key) but it just test that relation is specified.
And we don't test like that class respond to every single method but if we do test - we test what method does.

As we don't test other static things, like templates (like simple HTML with no logic) - we assume rails will generate specified HTML, it's impossible to break unless someone just change it.

At the other hand there is an argument can be made that relations are extremely important part of the app and in effort to have 100% coverage that also should be tested.

Usually in case of disagreements we look to best practices but I cannot find any mention of relation tests - neither to do it or not.

Can you please help me to find out is it common practice or not. (links to best practices that says about that or similar thing or your experience working with those)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked an opinion-based question that is hard to answer with sources, so you might need to rethink your question. However I'll give it a try.

I don't know about best practices, but in my opinion anything that can be accidentally changed should be tested, relationships/associations included. Now you want to find out how to avoid testing Rails logic, and instead just test that the relation was setup, but that's not tough to do.

Minitest suites I contribute to all have tests for the existence of expected relationships/associations.

Again, the idea is that if someone accidentally removes or adds a character or two to that line of code, there is a specific test to catch it. Not only that, but removing the line of code deliberately should also include removing a test deliberately.

Yes of course if someone wants to remove that line of code completely, and go remove a test, they should be able to do that. And at that point the assumption is that the entire task was deliberate. So that's not an argument to avoid testing in my opinion. The test is there to catch accidental mistakes, not deliberate actions.

Additionally, just because the test seems like copy/paste or repetition, that's also not a reason to avoid it in my opinion. The better the application code is, the more all tests will start to look repetitive or like copy/paste boilerplate. That's actually a good thing. It means the application code does just one small thing (and likely does it well). The more repetitive tests get, the easier they are to write, the more likely they are to be written, and the more you can refactor, simplify, and DRY them up as well.

In my opinion, this should be a best practice and I've not had much push-back from any of about a dozen other Rails developers I've worked with personally. And on a wider scale, the fact that `shoulda-matchers` have specific matchers for this means there are enough other developers out there wanting this capability.

Here is a minitest example of testing a relationship/association without testing Rails logic itself:

```
  test 'contains a belongs_to relationship to some models' do
    expected = [:owner, :make].sort
    actual   = Car.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name).sort

    assert_equal(expected, actual)
  end
```

To your point of the fact that it doesn't test the actual behavior of the code, and only tests that the relationship was defined when you'd expect a method written on a model to test the actual behavior of the method itself, not just that is was defined...
That's because you as an end-developer wrote that model method, so its behavior should be tested. But you do not want to test logic existing in the Rails core, as the Rails team has already written the tests for that.
Said another way, it makes perfect sense not to test the functionality of the association, but only test that it is defined, because the functionality is tested already by the Rails test suite.

Comment: The `have_many` matcher is not a part of rspec-rails. Its most likely from [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) which can be used with minitest as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info @max, I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

In our company we don't test Rails internal logic.
We don't check that Rails handle `has_many`, `belongs_to` etc. correctly.
Thats Rails intern stuff you shouldn't have to bother about.

Normally you have more than enough other stuff to test.

Comment: The question isn't talking about testing Rails internal logic. It is about testing application code. Maybe code some would consider boilerplate, but it is code written by the end-developer nonetheless.